# Android GridView Minimum Content Height

Tags: android, gridview, footer

I have a gridview in my activity and I use [GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter](https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter)

I added a footer logo to bottom of gridview and I want to align footer to bottom of page. This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want to make:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter gridLayout = (GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter) findViewById(R.id.categories_grid);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final ArrayList<Category> categories = (ArrayList<Category>) bundle.getSerializable("categories");

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View footerView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_logo, null);
    footerView.setFocusable(false);
    footerView.setClickable(false);
    footerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //
        }
    });
    gridLayout.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Comment: Is your footer fixed ? Means should it be at bottom most ?

Comment: @PiyushGupta Yes. This library's footer is fixed just below. I want to set footer's position to bottom of page.